# Build errors: "cannot find target for file" and "undefined reference"

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using codeblock and my compiler setting is `[-std=c++0x]`.
I created a simple project with the following code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Cat action;
    action.meow();
    action.jump();
    return 0;
}
```

**Cat.h**

```
#ifndef CAT_H_INCLUDED
#define CAT_H_INCLUDED

class Cat {
public:
    void meow();
    void jump();
};
#endif // CAT_H_INCLUDED
```

**CatProcess.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

void Cat::meow() {
    cout << "meow" << endl;
}
void Cat::jump() {
    cout <<"jump" << endl;
}
```

**Error messages:**

When I build and run the entire project, this error shows up on main.cpp line 8 on my IDE:

> undefined reference to 'Cat::meow()'

When I build and run `CatProcess.cpp`, this error shows up:

> error: Cannot find target for file

**Build log:**

> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++0x  -c C:\Users\Im_so\Documents\CodeBlock_Projects\ClassesForCats\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
>
> obj\Debug\main.o: In function 'main':
>   C:/Users/Im_so/Documents/CodeBlock_Projects/ClassesForCats/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to 'Cat::meow()'
>
> C:/Users/Im_so/Documents/CodeBlock_Projects/ClassesForCats/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to 'Cat::jump()'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default in Code::Blocks when you create new source file it isn't added to any build target. When creating file there are two checkboxes - Debug and Release. If you want to add already created file to a target, right-click on the file in codeblocks -> Properties -> Build and check Debug and Release.

Comment: It's working now! IThank you all so much! I'll remember to check it to prevent it from happening.